# Text replacement inside the string

Tags: php, regex

I have a string which looks like:

```
$data = '
 Some string
 [code=cpp]
 int a = 5;
 [/code]
 Another string
 [code=php]
 echo "5";
 [/code]';
```

And a function which takes 2 arguments: data inside code-tag and language (cpp, php, ...):

```
function Foo($data, $lang) { echo ...RESULT...; }
```

What is the best way to replace all code-tags inside `$data` using my `Foo` function? The result should be:

```
$data = 
 'Some string' . 
 Foo('int a = 5;', 'cpp') .
 'Another string' . 
 Foo('echo "5";', 'php');
```

---

```
function Foo($matches)
{
    echo SOME_ANOTHER($matches[2], $matches[1]);
}
preg_replace_callback('#\[code=(.*?)\](.*?)\[/code\]#si' , 'Foo', $data);
```

But this code doesn't save text outside the code-tags.

Comment: please tell what have you tried and where you stuck, that would be a starting point for others to help you in a better way.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function Foo($matches)
{
    return SOME_ANOTHER($matches[2], $matches[1]);
}
echo preg_replace_callback('#\[code=(.*?)\](.*?)\[/code\]#si' , 'Foo', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question, but this may point you in the correct direction.

```
<?php

$data = '
 Some string
 [code=cpp]
 int a = 5;
 [/code]
 Another string
 [code=php]
 echo "5";
 [/code] closing string';

 $d = preg_replace_callback('#\[code=(.*?)\](.*?)\[/code\]#si' , 'Foo', $data);

 var_dump($d);

 function Foo($matches){

    $code = trim($matches[2]);
    $lang = trim($matches[1]);

    //do what you want with the code ie:  int a = 5;
    //return 'FOO('.trim($code).', '.trim($lang) . ')'; 

    //run the side code...
    return exec($code); 
 }

?>
```